# Include CodeIgniter/Php web application within a genreated php page

Tags: php, codeigniter

The context:

I have a web application (e-commerce in few steps) written in php, I am writing a new version with CodeIgniter.
I have to include it within php pages generated by a CMS (sitezen).

```
/* generated html */ 
<?php include('my_app/index.php); ?>
/* generated html */
```

I cannot do anything about the CMS part, like working with an other one...

My problem:
With I cannot start the session before the header has been sent, I also get warnings when using the session but I can disable them.

My Workaround:
I didn't find any help relevant to my problem. The only workaround I could think of for the old php version is to send an ajax request to a php file starting the session.

This is working but there might be a better/cleaner solution, and I don't know how to do it with the CodeIgniter version.
I'd like to avoid using Iframes too!

If anyone knows a way to do it, or has any hint, it will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really be done without hacking the CMS considerably.

A CMS provides you with tools to do a specific job, so you are restricted to the CMS capabilities. Similiarly CI is a framework to help develop apps.

do you really have to include it within the CMS pages?

Why not create a link like:

`site.com/my_store_app/codeigniter-stuff`

then just link to it from within the CMS. You can reuse the existing template, so visually it will look like it's "within" the CMS, but you will be able to eliminate all these other problems.

You're essentially taking two completely different systems and attempting to stick them together.

Comment: Some of our programs use this method, but as ssice noted, everytime we update the website (menu,header,footer), we have to copy the generated code in headers and footers created for the other programs. Some clients might have 2 or 3 like these, and we have a bunch of clients ...

Comment: In the end we will just use another CMS, still testing. Your answer is what we are doing now, and it looks like there is no way around.

Comment: you *could* get around this if the template files are stored in a database. In CI you could create a model to return the appropriate template data and output it in to views. Depends on the CMS capabilities etc really ~

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter is a good framework for doing everything in it (as most frameworks), but doesn't like being 'included' from outside.
Why do you need to include him into a different CMS? You may do the CMS in CodeIgniter (that's the base purporse of CodeIgniter), or the e-commerce in sitezen.

If it is because of the surrounding styles, the best it occurs to me is to have it coded also in CodeIgniter. That's not great because you have to mantain styles twice, but it is one of the cleanest ways of achieving what you want.

Warnings are there because of a reason: disabling them does not prevent the result from happening.

What happens to you is that you try to start a session that has already been started. In order to avoid that, you must give the second session a different name from the first. (In a call previous to `session_start()`, you'll want to call `session_name()`.

Bad news are that once a session has been started, previous data from the session is no longer accesible, so if the CMS stores stuff in the session on `__destruct()`, the `$_SESSION` array where it stores the new data in will not be the same `$_SESSION()` used at the beginning of the CMS bootstrap.

And if you don't start a second session, you'll mix the CodeIgniter and sitezen variables inside the same array (beware of name collisions).

Code like this will NOT work (so, nesting sessions / restoring sessions is, as far as I know, not possible):

```
<?php
function show() {
    echo "We are on [{$_SESSION['name']}] <br />\n";
}

session_name('SUPERSESSION'); session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "Super";

session_name('SESSION_ONE'); session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "ONE";

show(); # We are on [ONE]

session_destroy();

session_name('SESSION_TWO'); session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = "TWO";

show(); # We are on [TWO]

session_destroy();

session_name('SESSION_ONE'); session_start();

show(); # We are on [empty] <- resume sessions does not work

session_destroy();

show(); # We are on [empty] <- nested sessions dont work

session_destroy();
```

To avoid headers already sent warning, start your code with ob_start() in your index.php, and ob_end_flush() at the end

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think sitezen is starting any session (which would actually be a good thing for me, I would just have to use a naming rule not to mess with its session). The warnings are only 'header already sent'. However, CodeIgniter doesn't use the PHP session, it has its own, I can't just do a 'session_start().'

Comment: CodeIgniter *does* a session_start() itself inside its own session bootstrap routine. And there's a config variable to change session_name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work for you but you could decide to include them trough curl. Another option is to include the pages directly. Do note that I'm not sure if this would work but if it does you won't be able to send PHP variables to it except trough the link.

```
include('http://www.example.com/codeigniter/controller/method/id');
```

Try this. If it works you can do something like this to control it:

```
include('http://www.example.com/codeigniter/'. $controller .'/'. $method .'/'. $id);
```

Note: sessions won't work on this method. If you really want sessions to work your best bet would be to separate the applications.

```
www.example.com <-- your cms
www.example.com/store <-- your webstore in CI
```

Comment: That won't work: CodeIgniter will serve an e-commerce, so it needs sessions for users. If it is the server who asks stuff, then there is no session handling (as you would send a cookie to your own server, instead of the real user).